# C getchar() works properly in terminal but not CLion

Tags: c, clion

The code below should first prompt "Type a Letter: ". Once enter is pressed, the output should show "You typed: `<achar>.`"

I'm using Jet Brains IDE, CLion. Yesterday the code worked as described above.  Today, however, when I run the code, I get a blank line. If a key is pressed followed by enter, I get the output:

```
Letter: You typed: <achar>
```

If, however, I put a \n after "Type a letter: ", the prompt shows but outputs the pressed key on the next line because of the \n.

I've copied the exact code into a .c file, compiled and run it in Terminal and it runs as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    printf("Type a letter: "); // works if \n used, but jumps to next line when key pressed
    c = getchar();
    printf("You typed: %c\n", c);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: That worked. But why? I assume flush is clearing used memory. But how come theres no issue in terminal? Put this as an answer with an explanation if you can and I'll mark it as answered.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal is buffered. `printf("Type a letter: ");` if the printf contains a newline(`'\n'`) it is printed. Without a newline, you can force the printf by calling `fflush(stdout);` otherwise the printf waits until the buffer is full before printing.
Be aware that input streams should NOT be flushed as `fflush(stdin);`

Answer (score 0):

It happens because after you type a letter and you hit ENTER you actually have your Letter (eg: `A`) and the new line  (`\n`)character. This means that you need to clean the Buffer.

Try the following:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;
    printf("Type a letter: "); // works if \n used, but jumps to next line when key pressed
    while((c = getchar()) != 0 && c != '\n' && c != EOF);

    printf("You typed: %c\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```